# Datos de entrada Python

Tags: python

Quiero ingresar por el teclado números separados por un espacio hasta que ingrese un cero
puedo ingresar números como lista pero no se como hacer para preguntar si es un cero y detenerlo
ejemplo:

```
datos = list(map(int, input().split(',')))
print(datos)
```

**Ejemplos de entradas**

**Ejemplo 1:**

```
1 2 3 4 0
```

**Ejemplo 2:**

```
 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 -5 0
```

**Ejemplo 3:**

```
-1 -3 5 3 1 0
```

**Salida Ejemplo 1:**

```
10
```

**Salida Ejemplo 2:**

```
40
```

**Salida Ejemplo 3:**

```
5
```

Quiero ingresar números separados por un espacio hasta que sea cero y sumarlos.

Se los agradecería si me pueden ayudar.

Comment: saludos que version de python usas?

Comment: Python 3."x"   No se si me podrias ayudar con lo que comente abajo

Comment: saludos no uses el area de respuesta para agregar parte de tu pregunta en su lugar editar tu pregunta [edit] y agrega los respectivos detalles

Answer (score 4):

Es un requisito un poco inusual el que pones, puesto que si el usuario teclea una línea en la que ha puesto muchos números separados por espacios, pero no aparece ningún cero ¿qué debe hacer el programa? ¿Pedirle más números? ¿Y si en la línea aparece un cero, pero después, separados por espacios, aún más números? ¿Debe ignorar los restantes y detenerse en el cero?

Si le vas a pedir los datos en una línea y separados por espacios, sería mucho más lógico finalizar cuando la línea se termine y no forzar a añadir un "terminador" artificial como es el cero. Este requisito del terminador es más habitual cuando se está en un bucle en el que se lee una línea (con un solo dato) en cada iteración, para saber cuándo parar.

Si nos dijeras el por qué de ese requisito tan extraño, quizás te podríamos sugerir otra forma mejor de hacerlo.

En cualquier caso, aquí te va una solución, que no es precisamente sencilla ni elegante, para hacer lo que pides, bajo las siguientes hipótesis:

1. Si en la línea introducida no se encuentra un cero, se pide otra línea
2. La lectura de datos se detiene tan pronto como se encuentre un cero, aún si hay más datos en la línea.
3. Si alguno de los datos no es interpretable como número (por ejemplo, si mete una letra), esta solución "romperá", aunque no sería muy dificil modificarla para que ignore ese caso por ejemplo.

Dicho esto, allá va la solución, que hace uso de una estructura de control ciertamente poco vista y poco usada, que es un `else` de un `for`, junto con otras dos un tanto "malditas" como son `break` y `continue`. Es programación poco estructurada, pero gracias a estos "trucos" se resuelve en unas pocas líneas:

```
print("Introduzca números separados por espacios y un cero al final")

lista = []
while True:
    linea = input("> ")
    for dato in linea.split():
        if dato == "0":
            break
        lista.append(int(dato))
    else:
        continue
    break

print(lista)
```

Ejemplo de funcionamiento:

```
Introduzca números separados por espacios y un cero al final
> 1 2 3 4
> 5 6 7 8
> 9 0 1 2
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

## Edición

Aquí tienes una versión que no usa `break`, ni `continue`, ni el `for/else` y por tanto podría considerarse más "purista". Pero es más farragosa, pues no es posible en este caso usar bucles `for`, debe hacerse todo con `while` y por tanto acceder a los iteradores "a bajo nivel", mediante la función `next()` y capturando la excepción `StopIteration` que se produce cuando se agota el iterador:

```
print("Introduzca números separados por espacios y un cero al final")

lista = []
otra_linea = True

while otra_linea:
    linea = input("> ")
    linea = iter(linea.split())
    otro_numero = True
    while otro_numero and otra_linea:
        try:
            dato = int(next(linea))
        except StopIteration:
            otro_numero = False
        if dato == 0:
            otra_linea = False
        elif otro_numero:
            lista.append(dato)

print(lista)
```

Como ves, ambas soluciones son muy feas y difíciles de comprender. Esto para mi es un síntoma de que el requisito está equivocado :-)

### Actualización

Tras ver los ejemplos de entradas que has añadido a la pregunta, veo que:

- Todas las entradas son de una sola línea, y todas terminan por cero
- Lo que querías en realidad era calcular la suma de los datos introducidos.

A la vista de esto, no veo sentido en hacer que el último dato sea un cero. Puedes dejar que el usuario meta números separados por espacios sin necesidad de obligarle a meter también un cero al final. El retorno de carro que pulsa el usuario dará por terminada la entrada, y por tanto la cadena que después podemos partir con `split()`.

La suma la calcularías así:

```
resultado = sum(int(n) for n in input().split())
```

Pero si pese a todo el usuario mete un cero al final, tampoco importa mucho y no necesitas detectarlo para excluirlo, puesto que sumar cero no alterará el resultado.

Así pues no necesitas todas las complejidades de mi anterior respuesta.